# Connecting Amazon Web Services with Elastic IP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Right now I have a domain ex: foobar.com hosted on Bluehost.
I created an instance on AWS and fortunately, I used (wordpress by bitnami) to migrate my foobar.com to the aws site.
I created an elastic ip and associated it with my instance.
This is where I am stuck. I've read tons of tutorials telling me to go into my Bluehost and add a DNS record which I haved.

My first attempt was to do a URL redirect on foobar.com, which worked but only for the homepage because when I would navigate to another page, it would display the elastic ip (ex: `53.13.153.12/about`).
I am unsure how to go about this problem.

Comment: You don't really need an EIP. Using a CNAME which points to the instance's DNS name should work just as well

Answer (score 0):

Setup an A Record, not a URL redirect. You'll need to then configure the vhost on your server to understand that domain (I think you may have already done this step).

Bluehost has some documentation [here](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/559)